# What does “Wouldn't it be nice if you could…?” mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does “Wouldn't it be nice if you could…?” mean?

Does "Wouldn't it be nice if you could ...?" imply "If you could ..., it would be nice."?

Comment: Can you provide more context (an example sentence)?

Comment: I would say that it implies, "It would be nice if you could..." as in, _Wouldn't it be nice if you could provide an example sentence?_ which is about the same as, _It would be nice if you could provide an example sentence._

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question first: not quite.  When you say "Wouldn't it be nice if you could ride a giraffe?" what you are saying is this: "I think it would be nice if you could ride a giraffe.  Don't you?"  When you say "Don't you?" instead of "Do you?" you are implying that you expect the person you are asking to agree.

This addition of the negative in a question has more general application, and it usually means you are encouraging agreement with your question.  For example:

> Do you think Joe is acting strangely?
>   Don't you think Joe is acting strangely?

In the first case, you are simply asking whether someone thinks Joe is acting strangely.  In the second case, you are saying that you think Joe is acting strangely, and you are expressing the expectation that the person you are asking will agree with you.

A little different example:

> You: Joe is acting strangely.
>   Me: Isn't he?

Here, I am saying that I agree with you.  And:

> You: It would be nice to be able to ride a giraffe.
>   Me: Wouldn't it?

Again, I'm agreeing with you.

It's a little complicated, isn't it?  :)

Answer (score 1):

"Wouldn't it be nice if you could..." is a common rhetorical question which can be translated to "It would be nice if you could...".